# Shorten time of notifications

Tags: xubuntu, notification

How can I shorten the time of notifications which show up in Xubuntu up right. About 2 seconds are enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have something called `Notifications` in your `/usr/share/applications` folder. You may also see it in your Xubuntu menu.

If you run that desktop file (the actual command being `xfce4-notifyd-config`), you'll get a small window titled `Notifications`. In that you can customize several parameters such as:
  - Theme
  - Default position
  - **Disappear after**
  - Opacity

You can also preview some of the changes.

[image: Xubuntu Notifications]